# RAM Specifications / HDD specs / System Compatibility?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, bios, computer-building

couple of questions:

I have recently acquired 8 older sticks of RAM, quite small individually...

- Pcm 256MB Pc-2100 (2 of these)
- D3 - 256 MB DDR - 400MHz - CL3
- 256MB DDR PC3200
- 256 MB, DDR, 400MHz, CL3
- AZEN 128MB PC133
- 128MB SDRAM 133/100MHz (2 of these) - these two are physically smaller sized.

Incidentally, I also have acquired a computer system, quite outdated, running Windows XP. My question is, how can I tell if my newly-acquired RAM sticks are compatible with this older system? I would like to beef its' performance up a tad bit.

I also have two internal HDDs - a 60GB, and a 20GB. My question regarding those is:

1. How to tell if either of the hard disk drives are compatible with the system I have (it is not a very advanced set of hardware in this computer, I assure you. I can't remember exactly, but the RAM is no more than 500MB and I'm pretty sure the processor clocks at 1.00GHz maybe? If that sounds like it makes sense? I dunno, I'm new at all this personally.
   And the hard drive that's already in it is 60GB, I'm pretty sure.
2. How to install a extra hard drive for more space (provided there is another bay for the second hard drive, I haven't checked for that yet - was more focused on the RAM compatibility at the time) - like, I know the original hard drive has cords/cables that go to the MOBO, the power supply - but won't I need another set of cords to add this second HDD? I don't believe I have them, but I do have some cords at home, I will come online after (I'm in class right now) when I get back and let you know what cords/wires I have for internal jobs like this.
3. What are the risks of static charges, because I don't have an antistatic wrist strap or anything like that...is there anything else I can do, wear rubber gloves maybe if I can find some? lol.
4. Once you plug in new RAM, that is it, right? You don't have to configure it in the BIOS or anything like that right?
5. Once you plug in the new HDD, provided I have the correct hookups and all that obviously, do I need to enter the BIOS or CMOS or whatever to configure THAT?

I know these are a lot of questions to answer, and I apologize for the lengthy first post. But I want to understand this, because this is something I'm interested in doing as a career and I need to be able to help other people with older systems as well as new ones.

Thank you!!

-TronJavolta

Comment: Drives: Up to 4 drives in most PCs, but we need to know either the make and model of the PC, or (if a clone) if the existing drives use the 40-wire grey ribbon cables, plus the makes and models of the hard drives you were given.  -1- Makes sense. -2- You will need a new drive cable for it. -3- Rubber gloves bad. Instead, don't work on carpet, work in kitchen. -4- BIOS will sense new RAM  -5- Probably will.  ** PC repair is a shrinking business since new machines are so cheap and also difficult to repair. **

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers, kiloseven! I will do as you suggested once home, and let you know more about the hardware. Thanks again

Comment: Repairing and Upgrading Your PC by Robert Bruce THompson is highly recommended.

Comment: http://freegeekvancouver.org/ http://www.freegeek.org/ and http://wiki.freegeek.org/index.php/Category:Free_Geek_Intergalactic might also be interesting to look at.